# Why does x+NULL result in NULL?

Tags: sql, null

I am trying to add two values from two columns, But i end up getting  few null as a result, because one column have a few null
Here's my query

```
select COL1,
       (COL2)+(COL3) as Total
from Table
```

Col2 has values say, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5

Col3 has values say, 5, 3, Null, null, 1

Column Total is spitting out NULL  for (3+null) and (4+null), but the other values are as they should be.

Could someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this because anything plus null is always null

What you want to be doing is:

```
select col1, isNull(col2,0) + isNull(col3,0) as total
from table
```

Please note that what I'm assuming is that the data type of col2 and col3 is int.  You have to do conversions to handle different data types.

Comment: Null means it is a Unknown or missing value.  So adding a know value to an unknown value means you have an Unknown value which is represented by Null.  So if you want to add up just the know values you need to do what Avitus has shown you.

Comment: I like using coalesce() function for replacing nulls in SQL.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thanks for putting in a way i can understand. Helps a lot. 
Will try using isnull and coalesce()